# $\vec{ds}$ vector of work formula

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, vectors, integration

I know $W= \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\vec{F}\,.\vec{ds}\ $

I am working with frictional force. Here $x_2>x_1$,  $\vec{F}$=  - $\mu mgcos\theta \hat{i}$

As $x_2>x_1$,  $\vec{ds}= \hat{i}dx $

So the integral turns out negative
But if I think to move the object from $x_2 $ to $ x_1$ and so think $\vec{ds}= -\hat{i}dx$ [ to represent direction of displacement ]

$\vec{F}$=  $\mu mgcos\theta \hat{i}$

Then my
$W= \int_{x_2}^{x_1}\vec{F}\,.\vec{ds}\ $
[ starting point $x_2$ now]

But this turns out positive.  But It can't be true. Where am I doing mistake?

Comment: Work can be positive or negative, depending on the direction of the displacement, and the direction that you define as positive.

Comment: You should be careful of what you've written, a better way would be $d\vec{s}= \pm \hat{i} dx$ as what you've written equates a differential to a unit vector and those things are not the same object.

Comment: @Triatticus you are right

Comment: $F$ is the force being exert _on_ the sliding object and you are calculating the work done _on_ the object. This work is negative because the kinetic energy of the object is decreasing i.e. when we add the work done on the object to the object's KE the result is smaller than the original energy.

Comment: It's very easy to get mixed up about the sign of work because the sign is just way of saying whether it's work done _by_ the object or work done _on_ the object. I still manage to get confused about this after 50 years! I usually don't worry too much about the sign and sort it out at the end by seeing if the total energy has increased or decreased.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is when you define

$$\vec{ds}= -\hat{i}dx$$

But still do the integration from $x_2$ to $x_1$. Since $x_2$ is located to the right and $x_1$ to the left, a movement from $x_2$ to $x_1$ is in the direction of $ds$, and therefore should be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with vectors, the $\vec{F}$ would become positive. and if you calculate $W$, you will get it as negative.

When going from $x_1 \to x_2$, displacement is positive and $F$ is negative and hence $W$ is negative

When going from $x_2 \to x_1$, displacement is negative and $F$ is positive and hence $W$ is still negative.

Comment: But the question is about the integral which shows it positive

Comment: where it shows positive, your assumption that the force is positive is wrong in the integral that is positive